# I was trying to fit and score logistic Regression model but getting error ,Can anyone help me this error

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

i am trying to experimenting Logistic Regression machine learning models, but i don't know why m i  getting error.

> ```
>                   models = {"Logistic Regression":LogisticRegression(),}
>              def fit_and_score(models,x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test):
>              np.random.seed(42)
>              model_scores = {}
>              #loop through model
>              for name, model in models.items():
>                 model.fit(x_train,y_train)
>                
>                 model_scores[name] = model.score(x_test,y_test)
>             return model_scores
>         
>      
>                model_scores = fit_and_score(models=models,
>                                     x_train=x_train,
>                                     x_test=x_test,
>                                     y_train=y_train,
>                                     y_test=y_test)
>                model_scores
> ```

---

> ```
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-33-9c05affc041a> in <module>
> ----> 1 model_score = fit_and_score(models=models,
>       2                             x_train=x_train,
>       3                             x_test=x_test,
>       4                             y_train=y_train,
>       5                             y_test=y_test)
>
> <ipython-input-32-b7a75c9edc31> in fit_and_score(models, x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)
>      21     for name , model in models.items():
>      22         # fit the model to the data
> ---> 23         model.fit(x_train,y_train)
>      24         # Evaluate the model and append it's score to model scores
>      25         model_scores[name] = model.score(x_test,y_test)
>
> ~\Desktop\heart_disease_project\env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py
> ```
>
> in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
> 1405         else:
> 1406             prefer = 'processes'
> -> 1407         fold_coefs_ = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose,
> 1408                                ***joblib_parallel_args(prefer=prefer))(
> 1409             path_func(X, y, pos_class=class*, Cs=[C_],
>
> ```
> ~\Desktop\heart_disease_project\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py
> ```
>
> in **call**(self, iterable)
> 1039             # remaining jobs.
> 1040             self._iterating = False
> -> 1041             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
> 1042                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
> 1043
>
> ```
> ~\Desktop\heart_disease_project\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py
> ```
>
> in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
> 857                 return False
> 858             else:
> --> 859                 self._dispatch(tasks)
> 860                 return True
> 861
>
> ```
> ~\Desktop\heart_disease_project\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py
> ```
>
> in _dispatch(self, batch)
> 775         with self._lock:
> 776             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
> --> 777             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
> 778             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
> 779             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to
>
> ```
> ~\Desktop\heart_disease_project\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py
> ```
>
> in apply_async(self, func, callback)
> 206     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
> 207         """Schedule a func to be run"""
> --> 208         result = ImmediateResult(func)
> 209         if callback:
> 210             callback(result)
>
> ```
> ~\Desktop\heart_disease_project\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py
> ```
>
> in **init**(self, batch)
> 570         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
> 571         # arguments in memory
> --> 572         self.results = batch()
> 573
> 574     def get(self):
>
> ```
> ~\Desktop\heart_disease_project\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py
> ```
>
> in **call**(self)
> 260         # change the default number of processes to -1
> 261         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
> --> 262             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
> 263                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
> 264
>
> ```
> ~\Desktop\heart_disease_project\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py
> ```
>
> in (.0)
> 260         # change the default number of processes to -1
> 261         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
> --> 262             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
> 263                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
>
> ```
> ~\Desktop\heart_disease_project\env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py
> ```
>
> in _logistic_regression_path(X, y, pos_class, Cs, fit_intercept,
> max_iter, tol, verbose, solver, coef, class_weight, dual, penalty,
> intercept_scaling, multi_class, random_state, check_input,
> max_squared_sum, sample_weight, l1_ratio)
> 760                 options={"iprint": iprint, "gtol": tol, "maxiter": max_iter}
> 761             )
> --> 762             n_iter_i = _check_optimize_result(
> 763                 solver, opt_res, max_iter,
> 764                 extra_warning_msg=_LOGISTIC_SOLVER_CONVERGENCE_MSG
>
> ```
> ~\Desktop\heart_disease_project\env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\optimize.py
> ```
>
> in _check_optimize_result(solver, result, max_iter, extra_warning_msg)
> 241                 "    [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/"](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/%22)
> 242                 "preprocessing.html"
> --> 243             ).format(solver, result.status, result.message.decode("latin1"))
> 244             if extra_warning_msg is not None:
> 245                 warning_msg += "\n" + extra_warning_msg
>
> ```
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
> ```

Comment: Please provide all error information instead of one line.

Comment: sorry i'm totally new to all this but here i'd shown full error

Comment: sorry，I'll try it according to your code. It's normal. I can't repeat your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried diffrent parameter and it solved the issue.

```
models = {"Logistic Regression" : LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear'),
          "KNN" : KNeighborsClassifier(),
          "Random Forest" : RandomForestClassifier()}
```